# Java: Generate a sequence of numbers within a range?

Tags: java, math

I need to be able to generate a series of ascending or descending numbers within a range.

```
public int nextInRange(int last, int min, int max, int delta, boolean descending) {
        delta *= descending ? -1 : 1;

        int result = last + delta;
        result %= max;
        return Math.max(result, min);
}
```

This works fine for ascending values, but not descending values. I've been staring at this for a while, and I'm not sure how to make it work for descending values. Any ideas?

Comment: create a loop that starts at your min value and ends on your max, and vice versa for descending

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the properties of the series are supposed to be, but in any case, the `descending` parameter seems redundant, since the caller could simply provide a negative value for `delta` which would be equally intuitive. Also, mixing the two schemes for restraining into the range (modulo for the top range, clamp at the bottom range) seems odd too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, where `delta` is negative when you want a descending sequence?

```
public int nextInRange(int last, int min, int max, int delta) {
    int result = last + delta;

    // now clip to min and max
    if (result > max) {
        result = max;
    } else if (result < min) {
        result = min;
    }

    return result;
}
```

or perhaps less straightforwardly, have the body of the function be the single line:

```
return Math.min(max, Math.max(last + delta, min));
```